# Node/add and node/edit do not display forms

Tags: nodes, theming

I am logged in as an admistrator account and all relevant permissions are enabled for admistrators(some rights to delete a few types are disabled).

When I attempt to edit or create an event I get a page with a bread crumb, a title and no actual form or styling. I checked the html and the form isn't being sent and just not displayed either. I am using drupal 7.14 and this setup was working before moving it to another server.

Comment: How big is your site? Is it possible to create a local version, using tools such as Backup & Migrate. This would make it easier to debug. Also there's a chance that the problem disappears which would make that a server issue...

Comment: It was previously local this problem did not occur until moving it to a rackspace server.

Comment: Then can you create another version on a subdomain for instance? Point being that these kind of issues are difficult to debug from afar... How was your website moved? Did you use ftp, git? Did you install Drupal then migrated content etc...

Comment: I can ask for remote access if there is something you would suggest checking in the filesystem. The thing is creating another version wouldn't help because we had another version and it didn't have any problems. It is likely a server issue like you said but I am unsure of what on the server would cause problems for editing or adding content but not for the rest of the admin menu or viewing pages normally.

Comment: A classic workflow is to have a local, staging & production version. The staging & production both on a remote server. This is more or less what I'm suggesting here. Create a staging version you can experiment with or use for debug purposes. When all is working move your content to the production site. In your case, depending on the size of your site , you could start with a clean Drupal install and move up from there... A problem with the server itself is unlikely ( although possible ). A bad site transfer seems more likely...

Comment: Just heard back from the person who did the migration it was SCP and a mysqldump

Comment: Yes I had a version working on my computer, then we had a version on the clients server and fixed all of the problems that cropped up there and when we switched to pulling from live data. What happened here is a breakdown in the move from staging to Production(not yet live).

Comment: I would recommend a combination of Git & Backup & Migrate. It's far more flexible... After editing on the client's server you would have sync'd your local version, then moved on to Production. In case something goes wrong, it should be fairly easy to do a quick reinstall. If things fail again, you can always test the Production server with a clean Drupal install as mentioned earlier...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8137/discussion-between-patricks-and-lathomas64)

Comment: Sorry about that I missed you asking that as I stepped away briefly to handle some laundry and make food.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the person who resolved the issue memory_limit on the server was the problem.

Comment: Do you have a reference to the issue?